# Adding jar dependency directory to Class-Path manifest using Maven maven-jar-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I'm using the maven-jar-plugin plugin and trying to add dependency jars to my jar:

https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <index>true</index>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The manifest.mf file then contains a list of all required dependencies; ie:

...
Class-Path: netty-all-4.1.22.Final.jar
...

However, my maven-dependency-plugin plugin specifies that the dependencies are placed in the /dependency-jars folder:

```
<configuration>
    <outputDirectory>
            ${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/
    </outputDirectory>
</configuration>
```

And so, the dependencies will not be found when we execute the jar.

Tag `<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>` automatically adds all specified dependencies, but how do I add a directory prefix to all of them?

Comment: Why do you need that? Why not using as a usual dependency? And why are you using maven-dependency-plugin to copy them into a directory? Are you trying to produce an executable jar?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to generate an executable jar. And I want all of my dependency stuff in its own sub-folder. AddClassPath auto-adds the dependencies but how does one prefix them with the folder they are actually in?

Comment: Based on your approach the jar itself is not executable because it depends on external directories filled with dependencies. The best approach is to go via maven-shade-plugin....that will produce a single jar which contains all needed deps...

Comment: Thanks. I have used shading/uber, but I believe there must be a way to get the auto-generated Class-Path to also include the dependency folder. Rather than giving up, I'll continue looking for a solution to correctly construct the manifest.

Comment: Found the answer in [https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html]: <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>. There's always a way :-)

Comment: So, what is the advantage to using the normal way, i.e. maven shade plugin or maven assembly plugin?

Comment: I'm adding the dependency jars in their own sub-folder with other external libs that can be accessed. Also, maybe a personal preference but don't like the bloated shaded/uber jar.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer is:

```
<classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
```

as detailed in:

https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html